# Append some text to a MultiLineEntry in fyne

Tags: user-interface, go, fyne

I want to append some text to this `MultiLineEntry` as a button event. I know how to set a text but couldn't find any example for **appending** some text. Is there any other `widget` available for this purpose? This is my code so far:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "fyne.io/fyne/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/widget"
)

func main() {
    a := app.New()
    w := a.NewWindow("Hello")

    largeText := widget.NewMultiLineEntry()
    largeText.SetText("Lorem ipsum ...")
    largeText.SetPlaceHolder("Type here")

    form := &widget.Form{
        Items: []*widget.FormItem{
        },
        OnCancel: func() {
            fmt.Println("Cancelled")
        },
        OnSubmit: func() {
            fmt.Println("Form submitted")
            // EVENT TO APPEND TO MULTILINE
        },
    }

    w.SetContent(container.NewVBox(form,largeText))

    w.ShowAndRun()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first get then set:

```golang
    largeText := widget.NewMultiLineEntry()
    largeText.SetText("Lorem ipsum ...")
    originalText := largeText.Text
    fmt.Println(originalText)
    newText := originalText + "appending new text"
    largeText.SetText(newText)
```

Comment: This will do what I wanted. But I hope there was a more straightforward way like using a widget or a built-in function.

Comment: @0_o You can post a issue to that project. https://github.com/fyne-io/fyne/issues